# How do I store values in an array within a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to get a bunch of numbers as input, and output it as first an unsorted array, then a sorted one. How do I store the inputted values inside the array within the for loop? Right now, it only stores the last value inputted.

```
String strNumberOfValues, strValue;
int intNumberOfValues, intValue;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter");
strNumberOfValues = input.nextLine();
intNumberOfValues = Integer.parseInt(strNumberOfValues);
 for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfValues; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter value for index value of " + i);
    strValue = input.nextLine();
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
    for (int j = 0; j == 0; j++) {
        int[] intArray = {
            intValue
        };
        System.out.println("Here is the unsorted list: \n" + Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare and initialize your array before the loop starts:

```
intNumberOfValues = Integer.parseInt(strNumberOfValues);
int[] intArray = new int[intNumOfValues];
for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfValues; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter value for index value of " + i);
    strValue = input.nextLine();
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
}
System.out.println("Here is the unsorted list: \n" + Arrays.toString(intArray));
. . .
```

Note that your inner loop is useless. It executes exactly one time and the loop index `j` is not used in the loop. All it does is limit the scope of the declaration for `intArray` even more, so the symbol is not defined even for the line that prints the array values. That print statement, by the way, should not execute until *all* the input values have been obtained, which is why I moved it to after the outer loop in my answer. (Note also that the variable `intValue` is no longer needed here and can be removed from the program unless used elsewhere.)

I'd also recommend, as a matter of style, that you avoid using the variable type as a prefix for your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare array first and then assign values based on index.

```
String strNumberOfValues, strValue;
int intNumberOfValues, intValue;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter");

strNumberOfValues = input.nextLine();
intNumberOfValues = Integer.parseInt(strNumberOfValues);

int [] intArray = new int[intNumberOfValues];

for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfValues; i++) {
   System.out.println("Please enter value for index value of " + i);
   strValue = input.nextLine();
   intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
   intArray[i] = intValue;
}
    System.out.println("Here is the unsorted list: \n" + Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Comment: Why exactly do you re-post an answer that was given almost three minutes ago?

Comment: :-) I started to answer this question before 5 minutes. But formatting took more time.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner for loop you are redeclaring the array every time, so only the last value is actually saved. You have to declare the array beforehand with the size that the user inputted then populate it index by index in a single for loop:

```
String strNumberOfValues, strValue;
int intNumberOfValues, intValue;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter");
strNumberOfValues = input.nextLine();
intNumberOfValues = Integer.parseInt(strNumberOfValues);
int[] intArray = new int[intNumberOfValues];

for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfValues; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter value for index value of " + i);
    strValue = input.nextLine();
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
    intArray[i] = intValue;
}
System.out.println("Here is the unsorted list: \n" + Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Comment: Please do not call an array a `List`. They are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Turing85 I just copied that print statement in the original question. The output might not be for a technical user. I think the word "list" is being used as a normal word, not as a reference to the structure in programming.

Comment: This is incorrect. A `List` is a dynamic datastructure. An array is not. Anyone using some kind of imperative programming language should know the difference (e.g. OP). If you do not want to write "array" (for the nontechnical end-user), you can avoid this by writing something like `"Here are the elements you entered: "`.

Comment: I know the difference between a list and an array. But the word list is not unique to programming, it is also defined as "a number of connected items or names written or printed consecutively, typically one below the other." Using the word was the choice of the person who asked the question, I didn't see a reason to change it to answer the question. Apparently none of the other people who answered did either. @Turing85

Comment: I totally get your point. But you confuse people, who are programmers. They will jump to conculsions that may not hold. This is the reason I proposed a mostly neutral formulation (which does not make use of the words "list" or "array") to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @Turing85 - The wording was present in OP's original code. There's no reason to make cosmetic changes to the code. In point of fact, the output verbiage is intended for the user of the program, not for the programmer, and depending on the audience, "list" may be exactly the correct term. Without more information than we have, there is no support for recommending a change.

Comment: The numbers are a list of integers that must be inputted by the user. Using list was not a reference to the structure, but just a list of numbers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Chinmayee no problem